# Refresh plot Chaco

Tags: python, qt, plot, chaco

I am trying to hide/show a line plot in Chaco. I have a reference to the name of the plot and the renderer

```
plot = Plot(....)
renderer = plot.plot((x, y), ...)[0]
renderer.visible = False
```

or

```
plot.hideplot(*[plot_name in plot.plots])
```

But none of these hides the plot. But when I resize the window, the plots are repainted and the plot lines are not shown. There seems to be a bug in the refresh of the plots when the visible flag is changed. Is there a way to force a repaint of the plot. I am using Chaco within Qt containers/layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help folks in the future:

I've forced a redrawing of my plots with:

```
plot.request_redraw()
```